# PHP - CSV file error "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to read a **.csv** file with php to **insert data into the database**.

The file is as follows:

> A50000,11-02-2022,15:00 - 20:00
>
> B50000,11-02-2022,15:00 - 20:00

I get the file with

```
$file = fopen("myFile.csv", "r");
```

and loop through each line of the file and insert it into the database

```
while (!feof($file)) {
    $csv_line = fgetcsv($file);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (xx, xx, xx) VALUES ('$csv_line[0]', '$csv_line[1]', '$csv_line[2]')"
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Finally, I close the file

```
fclose($file);
```

When I run the query to insert the data I get the following error: ***"Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"***.

As if `$csv_line[0]` is of type bool, but it is not. In fact, if I `echo $csv_line[0]` it returns a string.

What am I doing wrong?

.

.

**UPDATE**

This is the **var_dump of $csv_line** as requested

```
array(size=3)

  0 > 'A50000'(length=9)

  1 > '11-02-2022'(length=10)

  2 > '15:00 - 20:00'(length=13)

array(size=3)
    
  0 > 'B50000'(length=9)
    
  1 > '11-02-2022'(length=10)
    
  2 > '15:00 - 20:00'(length=13)
```

Comment: Please, **always** show us ALL the error message

Comment: Does the CSV file have a blank line between each real line like you show in the example?

Comment: [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#refsect1-function.fgetcsv-returnvalues)  _"Returns an indexed array containing the fields read on success, or false on failure."_ You should test the return before to use `$csv_line`.

Comment: _"As if $csv_line[0] is of type bool"_ - that is _not_ what the error message is saying, it says that `$csv_line` itself is a boolean - and that's why there are no "elements" that you could access via an index.

Comment: Add `var_dump($csv_line)` to your loop to debug. Also, you may want to use prepared statements, as your data may or may not be safe to interpolate into a query.

Comment: **DO You have a blank line at the end of the file?** Or **blank lines between each line** as per your example. If so that would cause this error

Comment: Per [manual](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv), "_A blank line in a CSV file will be returned as an array comprising a single null field, and will not be treated as an error._", however also "_returns null if an invalid stream is supplied or false on other errors[, including end of file]_" The note in brackets seems to not exist in the current manual. *Blank lines* would return `null`, and the error would read "...of type null", not "bool".

Comment: PHP8.1.1 produces `Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in....` when a blank line is reached

Comment: You still have not answered the question:: Do you have blank lines in this csv file?????

Comment: No, there are no empty lines in the CSV file, it is a typo here on StackOverflow. 

I have updated the post with the var_dump of $csv_line

Comment: @RiggsFolly I haven't blank lines in CSV file

Comment: How many of these errors do you get?

Comment: I guess, still the last line may consider as empty line, try adding the condition
`if(count($csv_line) != 3) continue` right at the starting of the loop

Comment: @AdiechaHK If I run this check, it tells me that $csv_line is not an array but a bool

Comment: @RiggsFolly I only receive one, as the second line is taken correctly

Comment: **I think I understand what's going on: the loop ignores the first line and gives an error if any data is present. I've tried leaving it empty and handling it with a control: if it's empty it skips it. Everything seems to work. Thanks for your help**